# how to increase 60 second timeout issue on Elastic Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-load-balancer, amazon-elb

We have use-case where we need to fulfill the request even after 60s.

We get Elastic Load Balancing Connection Timeout 504.

How to increase the timeout in ELB (aws).

Answer (score 9):

Well if you have configured your environment (load balancer) through Elastic beanstalk, then from AWS console

Services -> go to 'EC2'

Under Resources, select 'Load balancers'. Choose your load balancer, and under 'Attributes', click the 'Edit idle timeout' button. Set it to whatever value you want (in seconds).

[image: AWS ELB idle timeout config.]

Comment: Doubt. Is it fine to increase the Timeout from 60 sec to 120 sec. is there any issue?

Answer (score 2):

See the relevant [AWS documentation on ELB Connection Management](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elb-idle-timeout-control/)

Comment: The link provided is exactly what you asked for. Simply saying it's "not working" is not helpful and won't give anyone enough detail to be able to give you a solution to your problem. Did you actually set the timeout as the link suggests? What happened? What debugging steps did you take?